# % symbol is not displayed through

Tags: php, html, wordpress, symbols

I have this php code used for a milestone wordpress shortcode :

```
function rocknrolla_milestone_box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ){

extract( shortcode_atts(array(
    "count" => '90%',       
    "title" => ''
), $atts) );   
   echo htmlentities($count);

$rnr_milestone_box = '<div class="milestone-counter" data-perc="'. $count .'">';
$rnr_milestone_box .= '<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. $count .'</span>';
$rnr_milestone_box .= '<h6 class="milestone-details">'. $title .'</h6>';
$rnr_milestone_box .= '</div>';

return $rnr_milestone_box;

}

   add_shortcode('milestone_box', 'rocknrolla_milestone_box_shortcode');
```

Now, when I add on "data-perc" attribute 99% for example this is displaying a weird text like:

```
<span class="milestone-count highlight">NaN</span>
```

If I add just the number like 99 the output is correct:

```
 <span class="milestone-count highlight">99</span>
```

How can I append the % sign after the count variable here:

```
$rnr_milestone_box .= '<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. $count .'</span>';
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `data-perc`? What is the `$count` variable? and please... realy [read the notes](http://www.php.net/extract), and _don't use `extract`_

Comment: try appended % sign after $count..

Comment: you're saying to append the % sign in the $rnr_milestone_box; variable ?

Comment: I think I'm not appending correctly becuase is not displaying it, can you give me a correct example of appending in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this optimal option:

```
<?php
$count = "99%";
echo htmlentities($count);
// output: 99%
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you give me an example on my actual code structure?  I've tried this and it's not working. probably because I didn't add it corectly

Comment: use this one in your code <span class="milestone-count highlight">'. htmlentities($count) .'</span>

Comment: but where should I put the echo htmlentities ? I've updated my question with the code please take a look and tell me if it's correct

Comment: $rnr_milestone_box .= '<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. htmlentities($count) .'</span>';